# Symfony2 - Can I give an anonymous user a 'ROLE_SOMETHING'

Tags: security, symfony

I'm using the Symfony framework with the FOS User Bundle.  I'm using the security context to determine which menu items and other items to display.

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
if ($securityContext->isGranted($report['Permission'])){
    //add the menu item...
}
```

Is there any way to give a anonymous user a security context of 'ROLE_USER'?  I've got logged in users working properly.

I tried adding the line:

```
role_hierarchy:
    IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY: ROLE_USER
```

to my security.yml hoping this would do it, but apparently not.  I've Googled around a little bit and read the documentation.

I imagine that:

```
if ($securityContext->isGranted($report['Permission'])
    || ($report['Permission'] === 'ROLE_USER' && $securityContext->is_anonymous()))
```

would work, but this feels like kind of a hack (and not very DRY)

Edit:
This is for an intranet site.  I've got a table that contains names of reports.  Some reports should be able to be seen by everyone, regardless of if they are logged in or not.  Some reports require permissions to view.  I don't want to create several hundred users when only a handful will need access.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?  by default , giving a user role means he need to be logged in.

Comment: You can't because the pseudo role IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY serves only to the system authentication built-in in symfony to distinguish when a non authenticated user enter in some route covered by some firewall.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use a voter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html.  You end up with: $securityContext->isGranted('view',$report);  All the logic ends up in your voter class.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks I will investigate using a voter.  I had read about them but didn't realize that this would be a perfect use case for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to give access to people to a given url why not simply authorize it this way ?

You have 2 method to achieve this: create a firewall authorization or role defined a url

1) Firewall autorization

```
firewalls:
        test:
            pattern: ^/ws // you url or schema url with regex
            anonymous: true
```

2) url with a role defined access

```
access_control:
         - { path: ^/given-url, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }


// in app/config/security.yml
```

in both case, non authenticated user and authenticated user will have access to this url

By the way , if you want to test (in order to display some user variables) if a user is authenticated or not , just make your test in twig

```
   {% if app.user is defined and app.user is not null %} 
       The user {{ app.user.username }} is connected.
   {% else %}
       No user connected
   {% end %}
```

EDIT : Content based view : juste create a route for your action which would not match your firewall rules

Comment: Thanks, but I've got that part working.  I've made an edit to the post.  It's content creation that is also role based that I need to get working.

Comment: like my edit, you should edit your content view action route to a different url , in order not to match your firewall rules and then give access to that url to non authenticated user

Comment: I'm obviously doing a very poor job of explaining myself today.  Sorry.  I want to make decisions inside of my controller, based on security context, to decide whether it needs to add an item to an array that gets passed to my template to render. i.e. a list of reports.

Comment: so you need to remove from the firewall the route of your controller action and test if a user is logged in your controller action

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of what my "hack" in the original question is doing.

Comment: In That case this Is not considered as a hack or Your project code is badly built from the beginning :/